# How to customize title of browser's tab in drupal 7?

Tags: drupal-7, meta-tags

**My question is from "Drupal 7":**

“Consultants” is a custom Profile Type which contains many fields. “field_full_name” (machine name) is one of those fields which are defined in consultants profile type.
**Structure -> Profile Types -> consultants -> field_full_name**

What i want is to display something like:

### Consultants | field_full_name

in title of browser’s tab. The field type of “field_full_name” is text. I tried many things to get this desired result but unfortunately failed. Please suggest me what should I do to get this result.

Comment: Please suggest me from where i can learn preprocessor and hooks in drupal. Post the link of resouces...

Answer (score 1):

in drupal 7 many module do this features
one of them which i like is 
https://www.drupal.org/project/metatag

with this module you are able to set any field from your content type to set as meta tag
Hope this module solve your problem
thanks

Comment: i am surprised to know this its not working i used this many time i dont have emotions for printing here but :O

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can do it with the module Metatag. You also need to use Token, Field Tokens modules to get the desired functionality. See the following image. Here you can set your page title as you wish to.

[metatag and token together](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9JHvR.png)